# Lock-free swap of two unique_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, lock-free, atomic-swap

Swapping two `unique_ptr`s is not guaranteed to be threadsafe.

```
std::unique_ptr<T> a, b;
std::swap(a, b); // not threadsafe
```

Since I need atomic pointer swaps and since I like the ownership handling of `unique_ptr`, is there a simple way to combine them both?

---

Edit: If this is not possible, I am open for alternatives.  I at least want to do something like this:

```
threadshared_unique_ptr<T> global;

void f() {
   threadlocal_unique_ptr<T> local(new T(...));
   local.swap_content(global); // atomically for global
}
```

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in C++11?

Comment: First, how would you do this for `T*`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Honestly, I don't know. This is why I'm asking this question. I've relaxed my question a bit, should be possible now for `T*`.

Comment: There's a proposal to add atomic<unique_ptr> (and atomic<shared_ptr> ) at http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/n4058

Doesn't help you right now, but the commentary might be useful. (And I think confirms that going through a raw T* pointer that does work with atomic<> is the best you can do at the moment).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Lock-free swapping of two pointers

It seems there is no general lock-free solution for this problem. To do this, you need a possibility to atomically write new values into two non-continous memory locations. This is called [`DCAS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap), but it is not available in Intel processors.

### Lock-free transfer of ownership

This one is possible, as it is only needed to atomically save new value into `global` and receive its old value. My first idea was to use [`CAS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operation. Take a look at the following code to get an idea:

```
std::atomic<T*> global;

void f() {
   T* local = new T;
   T* temp = nullptr;
   do {
       temp = global;                                                   // 1
   } while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&global, &temp, local));  // 2

   delete temp;
}
```

Steps

1. Remember current `global` pointer in `temp`
2. Save `local` to `global` if `global` is still equal to `temp` (it wasn't changed by other thread). Try again if this is not true.

Actually, `CAS` is overkill there, as we do not do anything special with old `global` value before it is changed. So, we just can use atomic exchange operation:

```
std::atomic<T*> global;

void f() {
   T* local = new T;
   T* temp = std::atomic_exchange(&global, local);
   delete temp;
}
```

See Jonathan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465051/194635) for even more short and elegant solution.

Anyway, you will have to write your own smart pointer. You can't use this trick with standard `unique_ptr`.

Comment: what type of memory synchronization ordering would you set for the `std::atomic_exchange` operation? Is the default `memory_order_seq_cst` ok, or maybe overkill?

Answer (score 26):

The idiomatic way to modify two variables atomically is to use a lock.

You can't do it for `std::unique_ptr` without a lock. Even `std::atomic<int>` doesn't provide a way to swap two values atomically. You can update one atomically and get its previous value back, but a swap is conceptually three steps, in terms of the `std::atomic` API they are:

```
auto tmp = a.load();
tmp = b.exchange(tmp);
a.store(tmp);
```

This is an atomic *read* followed by an atomic *read-modify-write* followed by an atomic *write*. Each step can be done atomically, but you can't do all three atomically without a lock.

For a non-copyable value such as `std::unique_ptr<T>` you can't even use the `load` and `store` operations above, but must do:

```
auto tmp = a.exchange(nullptr);
tmp = b.exchange(tmp);
a.exchange(tmp);
```

This is three *read-modify-write* operations.  (You can't really use `std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<T>>` to do that, because it requires a trivially-copyable argument type, and `std::unique_ptr<T>` isn't any kind of copyable.)

To do it with fewer operations would need a different API that isn't supported by `std::atomic` because it can't be implemented because as Stas's answer says, it isn't possible with most processors.  The C++ standard is not in the habit of standardising functionality that is impossible on all contemporary architectures. (Not intentionally anyway!)

Edit: Your updated question asks about a very different problem, in the second example you don't need an atomic swap that affects two objects. Only `global` is shared between threads, so you don't care if updates to `local` are atomic, you just need to atomically update `global` and retrieve the old value. The canonical C++11 way to do that is with `std:atomic<T*>` and you don't even need a second variable:

```
atomic<T*> global;

void f() {
   delete global.exchange(new T(...));
}
```

This is a single *read-modify-write* operation.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! `CAS` is not needed there. Atomic exchange is more than enough. It seems I was too absorbed by the original problem and `CAS` already looked pretty simple) I will include this into my answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a valid solution to the

> You'll have to write your own smart pointer

```
template<typename T>
struct SmartAtomicPtr
{
    SmartAtomicPtr( T* newT )
    {
        update( newT );
    }
    ~SmartAtomicPtr()
    {
        update(nullptr);
    }
    void update( T* newT, std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst ) 
    {
        delete atomicTptr.exchange( newT, ord );
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> get(std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst) 
    { 
        keepAlive.reset( atomicTptr.load(ord) );
        return keepAlive;
    }
private:
    std::atomic<T*> atomicTptr{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<T> keepAlive;
};
```

it's based on @Jonathan Wakely's snippet at the end.

the hope is that things like this would be safe:

```
/*audio thread*/ auto t = ptr->get() ); 
/*GUI thread*/ ptr->update( new T() );
/*audio thread*/ t->doSomething();
```

the issue is that you could do something like this:

```
/*audio thread*/ auto* t = ptr->get(); 
/*GUI thread*/ ptr->update( new T() );
/*audio thread*/ t->doSomething();
```

and there's nothing to keep `t` alive on the audio thread when the GUI thread calls `ptr->update(...)`

Comment: Your constructor is inefficient, and uses `delete` on uninitialized garbage.  Use an initializer list to pass the arg to the `atomic<T*>` constructor, like `SmartAtomicPtr( T* newT ) : atomicTptr(newT) {}`.  Your destructor also doesn't need to do an atomic RMW, just a `get()`, unless you want it to be safe for multiple threads to destroy the object...

Comment: Also, you probably want to take a `std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst` parameter so you can do a relaxed update or get if you want, but the default ordering is still seq-cst.

Comment: For my own understanding (I'm new to this atomic stuff), I dug into std::atomic here in Xcode, trying to find where the garbage value you're talking about comes from.  

`607: #define _Atomic(x) __gcc_atomic::__gcc_atomic_t<x>`
`891:`
`struct __atomic_base  // false`
`{`
`mutable _Atomic(_Tp) __a_;  // <-- here?`
`1103:`
`template <class _Tp>`
`struct atomic<_Tp*>`
`: public __atomic_base<_Tp*>`
`{`
`typedef __atomic_base<_Tp*> __base;`
`1111:`
`_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR atomic(_Tp* __d) _NOEXCEPT : __base(__d) {}`

Comment: added recommended solutions @PeterCordes  thanks for the suggestions!!

Comment: It's safe now that you added a `{nullptr}` default argument for the `atomic<T*>` constructor, so you're just uselessly deleting a `nullptr` when you construct this, and doing an unnecessary atomic RMW.  Safe but slow.  Previously you were letting it get default-constructed, which would only be safe if it was in static storage.  In automatic or dynamic storage, `atomicTptr` would potentially be holding garbage before the `update()` in the constructor.

Comment: Anyway, the right place to ask for feedback like "Is this a valid solution?" is on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/